# create generic array of a specific length

Tags: java

I need to create a generic array of a specific length.

I have the generic array T[] originalArray and in some point in my code I will copy originalArray to a new array so I need to do something like:

```
T[] newArray = new T[originalArray.length()];
```

I've read that I cannot do this in Java but I cannot come up with a solution. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4):

```
T[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(originalArray, originalArray.length);
```

or

```
T[] newArray = (T[])Array.newInstance(
          originArray.getClass().getComponentType(),
          originArray.length );
```

(the 1st solution is reification safe - not that it matters)

Comment: @irreputable.. shouldn't it be just originalArray.length??

Comment: I don't think that work for me, I need to create the new array empty.

Comment: I have had so much of downvotes on some of my sensible answer.. But couldn't understand.  Why a downvote on this answer?? Downvoter should leave a comment rather..

Comment: Sure, `Object[]` can do everything. Though `T[]` is more strongly typed, since you can't do `newArray[0]="string"`. Even more strongly typed is `ArrayList<T>`.

Comment: @Rohin Jain...I'm so sorry. I'm kind of newbie in this website and thought that those arrows were some kind of scrolling tool.

Comment: you can also use `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance()`